# When does boruto series start?

Tags: naruto

After hearing so many rumours of boruto series I was just wondering when does it actually start if what's been said is true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to [Boruto: Naruto Next Generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boruto:_Naruto_Next_Generations) then the manga has already been out for a while (May 9, 2016) and is on-going. an anime, as indicated by wikipedia, is scheduled in japan in April

> A television adaptation is scheduled to start airing on TV Tokyo in April 2017.

this came from the cited source on [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-12-17/boruto-naruto-next-generations-anime-reveals-promo-video-key-visual-returning-cast/.110036) which was posted December 17th, 2016.

> TV Tokyo opened a website on Saturday to reveal the key visual, cast, and promotional video for the upcoming new Boruto anime series, titled Boruto: Naruto Next Generations. The television anime series will premiere in April.
>
> Crunchyroll is streaming the promotional video on Twitter with English subtitles.